# How do I integrate DelphiCodeCoverage with Jenkins?

Tags: delphi, jenkins, code-coverage

We are using this great free Delphi Code Coverage tool (https://sourceforge.net/projects/delphicodecoverage/). Now we want to integrate the code coverage results in our Jenkins pipelines. The tool can output an old EMMA format or XML format, but both seems not to be supported by the JaCoCo-plugin in Jenkins (this plugin replaced the EMMA plugin).

Does anybody has a clue how to get this working in Jenkins?